# How to trigger HTML password input on enter press

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to build a password prompt screen that redirects you somewhere after entering the correct password **and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>**. However, currently it only works by clicking the "Submit" button. I'd appreciate any help on how to adapt this code:

Here's what my code looks like for now:

```js
function checkPswd() {
  var confirmPassword = "asdf";
  var password = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
  if (password == confirmPassword) {
    window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=VT323');
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: table;
}

.div1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.div2 {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: VT323;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #656262;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: VT323;
  outline: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #656262;
}

.confirm {
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: VT323;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #656262;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <form>
      <input class="box" type="password" placeholder="123" id="pswd">
      <br>
      <input class="confirm" type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="checkPswd();" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `keyup` event to detect when a key is pressed and then check if its code is `13`, the code of <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If so, you can submit your form, or in your case call `checkPswd`.

**Code:**

```
/* Cache the password input. */
var pswd = document.getElementById("pswd");

/* Call 'checkPswd' when the 'Enter' key is released. */
pswd.onkeyup = function (e) {
   if (e.which == 13) checkPswd();
};

/* Prevent the form from submitting. */
pswd.parentElement.onsubmit = function () {
   return false;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! I'm afraid this does not work for me :/ I copied your (second) code to my pw.js file, but when entering the password and pressing the enter key, I get redirected to the same site, and the URL now has a question mark "https://mywebsite.com/?"

Comment: Check out my edit @Stephan. You need to return `false` inside the event handler to stop the redirection.

Comment: It's still the same: pressing enter reloads the page, clicking on submit gets me to google...

Comment: Still the same :( I'm testing this on Safari 11.0.2 and Firefox by the way. Enter just reloads the page, clicking submit redirects.

Comment: Have you tried using `return false` on the `submit` event, as I show above?

Comment: Yes, now pressing enter does nothing and clicking still redirects me to google.

Comment: I am sorry, pressing enter still does nothing... I've changed it to <form id="myform">, I hope that's what you meant

Comment: It will work now; I tested myself. Check it out @Stephan. I also removed the necessity of setting an `id` to your form.

Comment: I'm testing this on Windows and Mac, Safari and Firefox. Doesn't work :/

Comment: I've tested it on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari and it works everywhere @Stephan. Are you using the code from the newest edit? Also, are you certain your browser hasn't cached a previous version of your `JavaScript` file?

Comment: I don't know what to say anymore D: with your current code, pressing enter reloads the page, but does not redirect to google.com

Comment: This isn't possible unless your browser runs a cached version of your file before the changes or you are doing something to undo what's done above.

Comment: I just tried the following codes http://jsfiddle.net/aMgLK/ and http://jsfiddle.net/L01v8waL/ that should do something on an enter press, but they both do not work for me. What could be the issue here?

Comment: I don't know. I tested both and they work fine when `Enter` is pressed.

Comment: The fiddles work for me in the browser, but when I copy them to my website 1:1, they don't work

Comment: So, you're using some code that undoes my answer's code. Probably you're resetting the `submit` event or maybe there's a conflict between the code in your `JavaScript` file and the inline `JavaScript` code you use in `HTML`.

Comment: Found a solution: I used this js code from http://jsfiddle.net/L01v8waL and added the line `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to my HTML header to load jQuery!

Comment: I'm glad you found a working solution in the end. But loading the entire `jQuery` just for that is an overkill. Also, `e.keyCode` was used during the stone age. Now `e.which` is the standard.